# Cannot put/create files&folders on the Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Gnome Desktop

Tags: gnome

I do have a Desktop folder in my home folder.
When I right click on the desktop, only 3 options are shown, change background,display settings, setting.
I can't drag as there are no files shown, only 3 options:

[image: image 1]

I do have some files in my Desktop directory but none of the mare shown on the actual Desktop.

Desktop folder contains files,but not displayed on the actual desktop:

[image: image 2]

Please help me with solutions.

Answer (score 1):

To enable displaying items on the desktop itself:
First install `dconf-editor`.
What's dconf-editor?, from `dpkg -s dconf-editor`

> ...
>   Description: simple configuration storage system - graphical editor
>    DConf is a low-level key/value database designed for storing desktop
>    environment settings.
>    .
>    This package contains a graphical editor for settings stored in dconf.

install via apt/dpkg

```
sudo apt-get install -y dconf-editor
```

once installed

- goto <kbd>org</kbd> > <kbd>gnome</kbd> > <kbd>desktop</kbd>
  <kbd>backgroud</kbd>
- check **show-deskop-icons**

[image]

or alternatively from the command line use:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true
```

This has the advantage that you won't have to install any new packages (dconf-editor) however dconf-editor is nice for discovering the `SCHEMA[:PATH] KEY VALUE` values for building up your `gettings` command line commands.

Comment: Using a tweak tool is the fastest way